# Why is my character moving backwards?

Tags: 100-percent-orange-juice

While playing an online match of 100% Orange Juice, a red question mark began circling around my character's head. My character then started moving backwards around the board whenever it was my turn.

I didn't land on any traps, nor do I see anything in the card history that may have caused this.

Why is my character moving backwards around the board?

[image: Red circling question mark]

Comment: A question mark is generally a universal sign of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [latest set that was added for free](http://steamcommunity.com/games/282800/announcements/detail/3014457466384529909) (you still have to buy them in-game), one of the cards is "[Lost Child](http://onehundredpercentorangejuice.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Child)".

> Move backwards while this card is held. Cannot Norma while holding this card. This card is discarded upon KO or use.

Even if you didn't buy one yourself, someone else could have and everyone's deck is mixed for a game.

Lost Child is a gift type card, and like other gift type cards, an icon floats around your head to indicate you're holding it.

[image: Image of Lost child]

Comment: @Steven Vascellaro oh the wiki finally updated, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a unique field event called *Backtrack* defined in [the wiki](http://onehundredpercentorangejuice.wikia.com/wiki/Boards) as *Every 8 chapters, reverses the direction of movement for one chapter.*

Comment: This doesn’t make the question mark appear I believe. Additionally, backtrack applies to all characters, rather than just applying to on player